# Pipeline to deploy Net Core 3.1 webapp project and Azure Function App project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

In my current solution, I have two projects: A `Net Core 3.1 MVC` project and an `Azure Function App` project. Both are hosted in Azure, but in different resources (Webapp in an AppService, and the Function App project has its own Function App resource.

```
-SolutionName
 |_ WebApp Project
 |_ WebApp.AzureFunction project
```

In my current Azure DevOps pipeline, I have defined a build and deploy for the webapp only. How can I add a step that will take only the Azure Function App and deploys it to its respective resource?

EDIT: Based on the answer below, I have edited the yaml. The pipeline succeeds, but the zip for the azure function is empty.

My current yaml file looks like this:

```
# vm-image, variables, building of webapp removed for brevity.           
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Project Azure Function: WebApplicationTest.AzFunction'
  inputs:
    projects: 'WebApplicationTest.AzFunction.PipelineTest/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release'
    zipAfterPublish: false

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive Azure Function'
  inputs:
    rootFolderDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output/'
    includeRootFolder: false
    ArchiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/functions/azfunction.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Azure Function: WebApplicationTest.AzFunction.PipelineTest'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/functions'
    ArtifactName: 'functions'

#Deploy different artifact to different resources

# Deploy webapp step removed for brevity.

- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: Deploy to Azure Function
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
    appType: functionApp
    appName: 'WebApplicationTest-AzFunction-PipelineTest'
    package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/azfunction.zip'
```

I think it needs another step and then take the Azure Function App project from the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` package, and deploy it to my Function App resource. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: why not have two pipelines?

Comment: Isn't it easier to have everything in one pipeline? What if my project has more Function Apps, I would need an additional pipeline every time one is added. That seems not a good solution maintenance-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add a step that will take only the Azure Function App and deploys it to its respective resource?

We could build and generate different artifacts for those two projects.

We can **specify the full path of the project to be built and generate artifacts with different names for deployment to the perspective resource**.

For example, I added comments to the code to help understand my ideals:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'

#build the Web App, MVC project, and generate the artifact MVC.zip under the path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MVC
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish for MVC'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'MVC/MVC/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MVC'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MVC' 
    artifactName: 'MVC'

#build the Azure function App, AzureFunctionApp project, and generate the artifact function.zip under the path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/function

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build project for azure function'
  inputs:
    projects: MVC/AzureFunctionApp/AzureFunctionApp.csproj
    arguments: '--output publish_output --configuration Release'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'publish_output/'
    includeRootFolder: false 
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/function/function.zip'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Function'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/function'
    ArtifactName: Function

#Deploy different artifact to different resources

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'Subscription Name'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'WebApp Name'
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/MVC.zip'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    DeploymentType: 'webDeploy'

- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: Azure Function App Deploy
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
    appType: functionApp
    appName: $(appName)
    package: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/function.zip
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: Thnx, I am trying this out right now. What is `publish_output` in `arguments: '--output publish_output`  refer to?

Comment: @CMorgan, That is to specify the output result of the build, it can be other paths, just to facilitate us to know the file source path in the `ArchiveFiles` task.

Comment: okay, however, my zip file is empty. It seems to do the restoring and compiling into .dll fine (1 dll file), but then I have no idea what it is doing. All I see is that my published zip is empty, and the Archive step says it scanned 0 files, added no new data, and read 0 files from disk. The Publish Function step published to D:\a\1\s\publish_output\bin\AzFunction.dll. The rootFolderDirectory in the Archive step is '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output/'. 
I updated the main post.

Comment: @CMorgan, I changed the path to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output/`, but could not reproduce your issue, please share the debug log for the task DotNetCoreCLI build for azure function and ArchiveFiles task. I will check it om my side. BTW, you could share it by OneDrive with full **debug** log.

Comment: it works now. the artifact is prepared and downloaded correctly, and deployed to the correct resource in Azure. Thanks a lot for your time and patience. The difference between all the predefined variables is still unclear to me, but now it seems to work also with `'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'`.